# relation between dimension of a quasi projective variety and transcendence degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I think dimension of a quasi-projective variety is greater than transcendence degree of its regular function ring but I recently learn there are quasi projective variety with non-finitely generated ring of functions.can you give an example of a quasi projective variety $X$ such that $\dim(X)<\operatorname{tr.deg}(k[X])$

Comment: Rephrasing my earlier comment to: How do you define the "regular function ring" of a quasiprojective variety? This is something usually defined for affine *or* projective varieties, and the two notions differ accordingly.

Comment: a regular function is a rational function defined everywhere.(a quasiprojective variety sits in a projective variety and you can diffine rational function on it)